# TexStudio QT4-Ubuntu, why there vertical line dividing my editor into two halves?

Tags: texstudio, ubuntu

I am currently using TeXstudio 2.10.4 Qt4 under Ubuntu 15.10.
My problem is there is a vertical line divides my editor into two halves as in the screen-shot below, any idea how to remove it? 
[image: problem]
Thanks,

Comment: It might be the page delimiter, if you would like to print your source code for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the line width limit, if you specify wrapping after a fixed number of characters at `Options -> Advanced Editor -> Special Options -> Line Wrapping`.

The two lines exceeding the limit above are not wrapped because they contain no space. In that case, TXS prefers to exceed the width limit instead of wrapping because wrapping would introduce a space which might change the LaTeX code.